# How to import a git repository into another on a new branch

Tags: git

I have read multiple similar questions on SO, but I did not find a one close enough to my issue.

I have two offline repositories based on the same initial code `A`. These repositories have evolved on their own:

Repository `foo` located into `/home/foo/git/`:

```
        o--o--o A2
       /
A--o--o--o master 
    \
     o A1
```

Repository `bar` located into `/home/bar/git/`:

```
        o--------o--o A2
       /          \
A--o--o--o master  o--o--o A3
    \
     o--o--o A1
```

The idea is to import all of `bar` into `foo` on a new branch `B` named `bar` :

After the job, it should look like this on `foo`:

```
        o--o--o A2
       /
A--o--o--o master
 \  \      o--o--o B2
  \  o A1 /    \
   B--o--o B4   o--o--o B3
    \
     o--o--o B1
```

What is the simply way to do it?

### EXAMPLE

First, we want to create `foo` and `bar` like above:

#### Init the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DUMMY=dummy

commit ()
{
  openssl rand -hex 3 >> $DUMMY
  git commit -m "$1" .
}

# Create foo
mkdir foo && cd $_ && git init
touch dummy && git add $DUMMY
git commit -m "0" .
git branch A
commit 1
git checkout -b A1
commit 2
git checkout master
commit 3
commit 4
git checkout head~1 -b A2
commit 5
commit 6
commit 7

# Create bar
cd ..
mkdir bar && cd $_ && git init
touch dummy && git add $DUMMY
git commit -m "0" .
git branch A
commit 1
git checkout -b A1
commit 2 && commit 3 commit 4
git checkout master
commit 5 && commit 6
git checkout head~1 -b A2
commit 7 && commit 8 && commit 9
git checkout head~1 -b A3
commit a && commit b && commit c

# Show foo and bar
cd ../foo
echo "foo:"
git log --all --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'[%s]%d'

cd ../bar
echo "bar:"
git log --all --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'[%s]%d'
```

Which gives for `foo`

```
* [7] (HEAD, A2)
* [6]
* [5]
| * [2] (A1)
| | * [4] (master)
| |/
|/|
* | [3]
|/
* [1]
* [0] (A)
```

And for bar

```
* [9] (A2)
| * [c] (HEAD, A3)
| * [b]
| * [a]
|/
* [8]
* [7]
| * [3] (A1)
| * [2]
| | * [6] (master)
| |/
|/|
* | [5]
|/
* [1]
* [0] (A)
```

#### Svlasov's solution:

Then I tried to apply the solution of [svlasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005230/svlasov)

```
cd ../bar
git remote add foo ../foo
git push foo A:B
git push foo A1:B1
git push foo A2:B2
git push foo A3:B3

* [9] (B2)
| * [c] (B3)
| * [b]
| * [a]
|/
* [8]
* [7]
* [5]
| * [3] (B1)
| * [2]
|/
* [1]
* [0] (B)
* [7] (HEAD, A2)
* [6]
* [5]
| * [2] (A1)
| | * [4] (master)
| |/
|/|
* | [3]
|/
* [1]
* [0] (A)
```

The result is not really what expected. Moreover we need to do the merge manually. Can we do it automatically?

Comment: i think this might help you little http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

Comment: @UtsabNeupane not sure because in this example, we are moving directories. In my case I have the same sources in the same file structure. Or I did not understand this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cd /home/bar/git/
git remote add foo /home/foo/git/
git push foo A1:B1
git push foo A2:B2
git push foo A3:B3

             o----o--o A1
            /      \
bar: o--o--o        o--o--o A2
         \
          o--o--o A3

           +

           o--o--o A1
          /
foo: o--o--o--o A2
       \
        o A3

          |
          V

             o--o--o A1
            /
foo: o--o--o--o A2
      \  \        o--o--o B1
       \  o A3   /    \
        o--o----o      o--o--o B2
         \
          o--o--o B3
```

**Using your specific example**

This is my `bar`:

[image]

This is how I pushed the branches:

```
git remote add foo ~/foo
git push foo origin:bar-origin
git push foo bar1:bar1
git push foo bar2:bar2
git push foo bar3:bar3
# I forgot to push master :(
```

And this in my `foo` afterwards:

[image]

`bar` graph is recognizable. A more generic solution would be to iterate over all branches and add some prefix to every new branch name, like I did with `bar-origin`, but I prefer more manual work with total control.

Comment: Do `A:B` are commit references where A is the root node on the destination (foo) and B the cut tree at its base? If so I get an error `error: src refspec 477b142 does not match any.`

Comment: `A` is the existing branch name in both `bar` and `foo`, `B` is the new branch name that will be created in `foo`.

Comment: I made some tests and it doesn't really work. On `foo` I don't get all the  `bar` tree, but only the commit on the branch `A`

Comment: You need to repeat the procedure for the rest of the branches. Except that you need to use a different branch name every time, to avoid existing branch overwrite.

Comment: I made an update to my question. In the meantime I noticed you modified your answer. Is it possible to make it more generic? In the real world, the `bar` repository has lots of branches...